# anyone know what kind of breed my kitty looks like?

Tags: cats, breeds, crossbreed

my girl Tippy was adopted from an animal shelter and i was wondering what she looked like. her dad is unknown but her mom was a short haired kitty that was all white but with two big black spots on her back. Tippy isn’t going to be short haired i believe though since the thickness of her hair and the tuffs on the inside of her ears and toes. probably medium to short i’d say, anyways any info is helpful, thanks!![image][image][image]
[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because breed identification questions are off topic and any answer to this will be based on each and everyones opinion.

Comment: if you want to learn about the origin and the needs of cats this is a good source http://learnonline.cats.org.uk/content/ufo/index.html

Comment: She looks like a domestic short haired tortoiseshell.

Comment: DSH calico. :) At least in the US, tortoiseshell and calico are different colorings, with the distinction being the presence (calico) or absence (tortoiseshell) of white. Calico and tortoiseshell are not breeds, just colors.